# Reference navigation property not loading (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I got 3 models: `Human`, `Skill` and `HumanSkill`. There is a many to many relationship between `Human` and `Skill`, the `HumanSkill` is the intermediary table between them.

My query to the database loads the collection of the intermediary table `HumanSkill` correctly, but does not load the reference navigation property `Skill` through which I want to load the `Skill` name (`Human ->  HumanSkill -> Skill -> Skill.name`) using a query projection with select.

```
public IActionResult Preview(int humanId)
{
    var currentHuman = this.db.Humans
                              .Where(x => x.Id == humanId)
                              .Select(r => new HumanPreviewViewModel
                                      {
                                          PrimaryData = r.PrimaryData,
                                          // How should I write this line?
                                          Skills = r.Skills.ToList(), 
                                      }).SingleOrDefault();

    return View(currentResume);
}
```

Human model:

```
public class Human
{
    public Human()
    {
        this.Skills = new HashSet<HumanSkill>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual PrimaryData PrimaryData { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HumanSkill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

`HumanSkill` model:

```
public class HumanSkill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int HumanId { get; set; }
    public Human Human { get; set; }

    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public Skill Skill { get; set; }
}
```

Skill model:

```
public class Skill
{
    public Skill()
    {
        this.Humans = new HashSet<HumanSkill>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HumanSkill> Humans { get; set; }
}
```

HumanPreviewViewModel:

```
public class HumanPreviewViewModel
    {
        public HumanPreviewViewModel()
        {
        }
        public PrimaryData PrimaryData { get; set; }

        public List<HumanSkill> Skills { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can query on `HumanSkill` and then use `Include` for `Skill`

Comment: How can I achieve this without using include? I prefer query projections.

Comment: Use some data from `Skill` in either the Select or the Where..

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve this without using include?

If you use some data from Skills table in the Select, EF will perform the necessary joins to retrieve the data

```
  var currentHuman = this.db.Humans
      .Where(x => x.Id == humanId)
      .Select(r => new HumanPreviewViewModel
              {
                  PrimaryData = r.PrimaryData,
                  SkillNames = r.Skills.Select(hs => hs.Skill.Name).ToList(), 
              }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I would like to load the names of skills into the List of HumanSkill as presented in the ViewModel. I do not wish to create a List of skill names separately. Is that possible?

Comment: My psot was just an example of the "access the data in the select" point I was making. Your viewModel doesn't quite make sense because it doesn't appear to go deep enough; for your VM to reference a DB entity HumanSkill is illogical. Your VM should perhaps have a `List<SkillViewModel>` ?

Comment: My `HumanPreviewViewModel` has only two properties: `PrimaryData PrimaryData` and `List<HumanSkill> Skills`.

Comment: Which *is* a bit confusing because `HumanSkill` is a DB entity, not a viewmodel. Your viewmodel should have only things that are simple props (string, int) or  xxviewmodels (themselves only simple props or viewmodels)... It should have e.g. `List<HumanSkillViewModel>`

Answer (score 0):

When projecting from entity to a view model, avoid mixing them. For example, do not have a view model contain a reference or set of entities. While it might not seem necessary, if you want a list of the skills with their ID and name in the HumanPreviewViewModel then create a serialize-able view model for the skill as well as the PrimaryData if that is another related entity. Where PrimaryData might be a one-to-one or a many-to-one the desired properties from this relation can be "flattened" into the view model.

```
[Serializable]
public class HumanPreviewViewModel
{
    public Id { get; set; }
    public string DataPoint1 { get; set; }
    public string DataPoint2 { get; set; }

    public List<SkillViewModel> Skills { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SkillViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you go to extract your Humans:

```
var currentHuman = this.db.Humans
    .Where(x => x.Id == humanId)
    .Select(r => new HumanPreviewViewModel
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        DataPoint1 = r.PrimaryData.DataPoint1,
        DataPoint2 = r.PrimaryData.DataPoint2,
        Skills = r.Skills.Select(s => new SkillViewModel
        {
            Id = s.Skill.Id,
            Name = s.Skill.Name
        }).ToList()
    }).SingleOrDefault();
```

The reason you don't mix view models and entities even if they share all of the desired fields is that your entities will typically contain references to more entities. When something like your view model gets sent to a Serializer such as to send to a client from an API or due to a page calling something an innocent looking as:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

then the serializer can, and will touch navigation properties in your referenced entities which will trigger numerous lazy load calls.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with this information. I am new to ASP.NET and will read more on this topic.